# Curvature formula derivation in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$ in case of non-invertible speed

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

In section $14.14$, Tom Apostol is deriving curvature vector as follows:

$$
\frac{dT}{ds} = \frac{dt}{ds} \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{1}{s'(t)} T'(t) = \frac{1}{v(t)}T'(t)
$$

As far as I'm aware (theorem $6.7$ in his book), $\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{s'(t)}$ only if $s(t)$ has inverse, and in general speed $v(t)$ does not have to have one. Furthermore, if $v(t)$ does not have an inverse, then $\frac{dt}{dv}$ doesn't seem to even make sense.

How should I justify that derivation?

Thanks!

---

Note:

$v(t) = \|X'(t)\|$ is the speed, the magnitude of the first derivative of the position vector.

$t$ is a parameter of the curve.

$T(t) = \frac{X'(t)}{\|X'(t)\|}$ is the unit tangent vector.

Comment: After having looked through Theorem 6.7, I think that what it actually means is that $\frac{dx}{df(x)}=(\frac{df}{dx})^{-1}$ only holds for invertible function. But for a non-invertible case, let us take $\frac{dx}{d\sin(x)}$. If we want the value of the derivative at $x=a$, we can simply take a neighbourhood small enough around $a$ in which the function _is_ invertible and use that.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Can you please promote that to the full answer so we can close the question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Going to do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having looked through the Theorem 6.7, I think that what it actually means is that $$\frac{dx}{df(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{df(x)}{dx}}$$ only holds if $f(x)$ is an invertible function.

But suppose we have a non-invertible function, maybe $\sin(x)$ for example. In this case, for analysing the value of $\frac{dx}{d\sin(x)}$ around $x=a$ we can take a small enough neighbourhood around $a$ in which the function *is* invertible and use that region.

This ought to work for most well-behaved functions, but if someone can come up with a function that doesn’t satisfy this definition, please comment.